# match the file content and pass the test

Tags: python, bash, csh

I want pass the status as true if the data in the File1 matches in File2, although if File2 contains addition data that's okay.

Looking around a way to test with bash or shell.

File1:

```
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/nn/QA/OL-develop/bin
```

File2:

```
PATH=/home/nn/QA/OL-develop/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/niraj/QA/OL-develop/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `grep` for this:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2
```

- `-f file1` takes newline separated patterns to match from `file1`
- `-F` takes the pattern literally i.e. no Regex interpretation; drop `-F` if you don't want this behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file1.txt","r") as file1:
    with open("file2.txt","r") as file2:
        print(file1.read() in file2.read())
```

You could try this python script

Comment: this will obvious will give false.